# Format data in generated csv file using php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am generating an exam report csv file for my project but I wanted to customize the data that will be inserted on the exported csv file. How do I do that? I am using php Codeigniter for this.

As of now, my code can generate a csv file containing the questions and the number of correct and wrong answers for that question.

here is a picture of the downloaded file. [Generated CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SEzi.png)

But I wanted it to look like this:

[Wanted Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4qH1.png)

Here is my controller and model:
Controller:

```
public function csv_report($exam_no){
    $this->load->model('instant_model');
    $median = $this->median($exam_no);

    $this->instant_model->exportToCSV($exam_no);
}
```

Model:

```
public function exportToCSV($exam_no){

        $this->load->dbutil();
        $this->load->helper('file');
        $this->load->helper('download');

        $delimiter = ",";      
        $newline = "\r\n";
        $filename = "exam_report.csv";
        $query = " SELECT DISTINCT(questions.question_id), questions.question, 
            (SELECT count(score) FROM exam_set WHERE exam_no = '$exam_no' AND score > 0 AND questions.question_id = exam_set.question_id) AS correct , 
            (SELECT count(score) FROM exam_set WHERE exam_no = '$exam_no' AND score = 0 AND questions.question_id = exam_set.question_id) AS wrong 
            FROM questions INNER JOIN exam_set ON (questions.question_id = exam_set.question_id) WHERE exam_no = '$exam_no';";

         $result = $this->db->query($query);
        $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline);

        force_download($filename, $data);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you already have csv output for your result, but you just want to append data to it. So let's create a function which gives CSV line to us.

```
function get_csv_line(array $row, $delim = ',', $newline = "\n", $enclosure = '"')
{
 $line = array();
 foreach ($row as $item)
 {
    $line[] = $enclosure.str_replace($enclosure, $enclosure.$enclosure, $item).$enclosure;
 }
 $out .= implode($delim, $line).$newline;
 return $out;
}
```

Edit your code block as below

```
$data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline);
$row1 = array('mean','maximum','minimum','variance','median');
// replace your values.
$row2 = array(4.66,5,3,7,8);
$out1 = get_csv_line($row1, $delimiter, $newline);
$out2 = get_csv_line($row2, $delimiter, $newline);
$data .= $out1.$out2;

 force_download($filename, $data);
```

Comment: It works, but then what if the appended data come from the database? I tried replacing $row2 values as a query. But then it doesn't show the data it  displays 'Array' and 'Resource id #36' in the csv cells.

Comment: don't replace with query. replace with  `$row2 = $result->row_array()`

Comment: enjoy coding :)